# Why std::variant in C++17 allows std::variant<int, const int>

Tags: c++, c++17

In http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0088r3.html there is a note about the need to expand on `std::variant<int, const int>`, and voting for allowing it, but I can't find the actual rationale.

So why would it make sense to allow for `std::variant<int, const int>`?

Comment: Why don't you read that link? It explains the rationale pretty well. It actually explains it in the first line of the introduction.

Comment: Sorry @EliSadoff, the first line of the introduction says "C++17 needs a type-safe union:", could you expand?

Comment: C++ does not currently have a type safe union and allowing for a `int` `const int` union allows for there to be a type safe union. This will help to reduce unsafe type exceptions. The included code in the proposal is an example of why this is needed.

Comment: @EliSadoff Given they voted on it and got 1 neutral vote, 1 weakly against and even 1 strongly against vote it appears to be not *that* clear that `variant` should support this.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I personally think that it can be helpful, but it's a mixed bag. I was just giving rationale as to why one might want it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: "*Given they voted on it and got 1 neutral vote, 1 weakly against and even 1 strongly against vote it appears to be not that clear that variant should support this.*" There was still a supermajority+ of people who supported it. That shows consensus from the standards committee.

Comment: Some sections have been removed from later versions of the document. An early version where you can find some details is [N4450](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4450.pdf#11).

Comment: @NicolBolas Not arguing with that, just saying that it is not immediately clear it is a good idea. At least not *"It actually explains it in the first line of the introduction."*-clear (see very first comment).

Comment: @bogdan : If you would you like to post your comment as as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale and discussion sections that were present in earlier versions of the paper have been separated into [P0086 - Variant design review](http://wg21.link/p0086).

The relevant paragraph says:

> `variant<int, const int>` A `variant` can handle `const` types: they
>   can only be set through `variant` construction and `emplace()`. If
>   both `const` and non-`const` types are alternatives, the active
>   alternative is chosen by regular constructor instantiation / overload
>   rules, just as for any other possibly matching alternative types.

So, in terms of rationale, looking through the section on alternatives we can say that:

- The fewer requirements on alternative types there are, the easier it is to use `variant` in template code. (Otherwise, template code would have to go through a list of types, remove cv-qualifiers, eliminate duplicates, and so on before instantiating a `variant` with them.)
- Allowing cv-qualified types in general, and the same type with different cv-qualifications in particular, can be implemented with semantics that flow naturally from the nature of the types.